# Insert form inputs with the same input name into database rows using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I have a form with similar form input name which I would like to insert into different rows of database table. But when I submit form, the inputs with similar form input name don't get inserted.

Here is my view

```
<div class="row">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="item-block">
              <div class="item-form">

                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-float btn-remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></button>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="skills_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill name, e.g. HTML">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="skills_proficiency[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill proficiency, e.g. 90">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 duplicateable-content">
            <div class="item-block">
              <div class="item-form">

                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-float btn-remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></button>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="skills_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill name, e.g. HTML">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="skills_proficiency[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Skill proficiency, e.g. 90">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-duplicator">Add experience</button>
          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END Skills -->
```

Controller:

```
function _get_skills_data(){

    $data4['skills_name'] = $this->input->post('skills_name', TRUE);
    $data4['skills_proficiency'] = $this->input->post('skills_proficiency', TRUE);
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data4['user_id'] = $session_data['user_id'];

    return $data4;

}

if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)
            {
                    $this->add_resume();
            }
            else
            {

                    $data4 = $this->_get_skills_data();


                    $this->User_model->insert_resume('skills',$data4);

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success">Resume Added</div>');


                    redirect('user/manage_resume', 'refresh');
            }
```

model:

```
function insert_resume($table, $data){

$query = $this->db->insert($table, $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

}

Please what am i getting wrong,I have read some questions on this which isn't working for me. Thank you!

Comment: for firstly forget CI try to make the form like in core php and html then post the form, after that try in ci

Comment: In model write `echo $this->db->last_query()` before `return `. See what query is built.

Comment: The post `skills_name[]` is coming through as an array, you need to loop the array and build the insert script that way.  At the moment I think you are trying to insert an array into the database.

Comment: Yes I am trying to insert an array into different database rows. I've tried looping through, and I get Array to string conversion error

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query() didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Blinkydamo's Comment you need to loop over your post data because you try to insert these as an array

try something like this:

```
function _get_skills_data()
{
    $arrData = array();
    $arrPostSkillsName = $this->input->post('skills_name', TRUE);
    $arrPostSkillsProficiency = $this->input->post('skills_proficiency', TRUE);
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    $count = count($arrPostSkillsName);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $arrItemData = array();
        $arrItemData['skills_name'] = $arrPostSkillsName[$i];
        $arrItemData['skills_proficiency'] = $arrPostSkillsProficiency[$i];
        $arrItemData['user_id'] = $session_data['user_id'];

        $arrData[] = $arrItemData;
    }

    return $arrData;
}
```

and your second controller function snippet

```
if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)
{
    $this->add_resume();
}
else
{
    $arrData = $this->_get_skills_data();
    foreach($arrData AS $arrItemData)
    {
        $this->User_model->insert_resume('skills',$arrItemData);
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success">Resume Added</div>');
    redirect('user/manage_resume', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: But it adds one additional empty input into the database where could that be coming from

Comment: i've no idea - you've to print out the array - but i think the problem is, you leave the fields in your html form empty;

maybe you do a check on the _get_skills_data function whether the data are set or not

Comment: Thanks @sintakonte